# How do you iterate through multiple variables in a f string

Tags: python, loops

Essentially, I need to print the following for each letter 100x

```
print(f"https://www.gurufocus.com/stock_list.php?m_country[]=USA&a={letter}&p={i}&n=30")
```

I am able to loop through the number and print it 100x but am unsure how move to the next letter until it reaches the letter Z. Any help would be appreciated.

**I am looking to have it run 100x for each letter.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
number = 0
letter = 'A'
while number  < 100:
    print(f"https://www.gurufocus.com/stock_list.php?m_country[]=USA&a={letter}&p={i}&n=30")
    letter = bytes(letter, 'utf-8')
    letter = str(bytes(letter[0] + 1)).upper()
    number  += 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"iterate through ... the letter, and the number"*? You've given some code with a `while` loop; does this code not do what you want, and if not, what specifically is the difference between what it does and what you want it to do instead?

Comment: Apologies, I know it was a little unclear. Right now the code just prints the line 100x moving the number index until it reaches 100. However, once it does this, I need it to shift to the next letter in the alphabet and do the same thing again.

Answer (score 0):

f-string use

```
import string

for letter in string.ascii_uppercase: # you can change if you need lower, string.ascii_lowercase
    for i in range(100):
        url = f"https://www.gurufocus.com/stock_list.php?m_country[]=USA&a={letter}&p={i}&n=30"
        print(url)
```

Past Answer

```
import string

url_form = "https://www.gurufocus.com/stock_list.php?m_country[]=USA&a={letter}&p={i}&n=30"
for letter in string.ascii_uppercase: # you can change if you need lower, string.ascii_lowercase
    for i in range(100):
        url = url_form.format(letter=letter, i=i)
        print(url)
'''
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to use f strings

Comment: Sorry, there was a code error, I uploaded it again.

Comment: Thanks! The second code worked! Also adjusted it to use with f string

Comment: Oops Sorry, I misunderstood the question.
I edited it to use f-string. check please